# Stripping non-breaking spacesfrom FreeTextBox

Tags: .net, regex, freetextbox

I've not had this problem before and I'm stumped.  Using FTB and cannot find a way to strip non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) from the text entry into and out of `sql2008r2`.  I've done this many, many times with regular textboxes and textareas, but this has me done in.  I've tried simple `replace(string,"&nbsp;","")` on the page without luck, but prefer to use a regex.  And, neither of these works:

```
Regex.Replace(endStr, "(Â){1,999}", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Regex.Replace(endStr, "(&nbsp;){1,999}", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

Never mind, found this and it works great:

```
Regex.Replace(endStr, "\s+", " ",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: you can answer this and accept your own answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

\p{Z}+ should work even better if your textbox is going to deal with asian languages as their spacing characters differ from standard Unicode values.